# Simple string concatenation in rails in view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails. Can someone please explain to me the concept of string concatenation using variables in view page and the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in view

```
<%
  var1 = "ruby"
  var2 = "on"
  var3 = var1 + var2
%>
```

Finally

```
<% f_var = "Ruby #{var3}"%>
```

but this type of  code is not recommended in view as it does not look good. You should use helper method for this type of requirement

Answer (score 5):

For example :

In controller Code :

```
def show
   @firstname = 'Test'
   @lastname = 'User'
end
```

In view page :

```
Full Name : <%= "#{@firstname}  #{lastname}" %>
```

For further details [Click Here](http://www.tricksonrails.com/2009/12/string-concatenation-performance-ruby-tricks-02/)

Scenarios:- If you want to keep two variables on View page and add concatenation for those then use of space is necessary.

View page:

```
<%
  var string_1 = "With"
  var string_2 = "Rails"

  var addition_1 = string_1 + string_2;
  var addition_2 = string_1 + " " + string_2

%>
<h1> First Addition  -> #{addition_1} </h1>
<h1> Second Addition  -> #{addition_2} </h1>
```

Output :

```
First Addition  -> WithRails
Second Addition  -> With Rails
```

Comment: ok thanks i am not asking this Example create the variable in view page the variable which having the string value then that variable should be used in another string content. For instant `@var = "Rails"<br>Ruby on @var`